# Time difference in two click in Uiautomator

Tags: android, ui-automation

I am using UiAutomator to measure the time difference between two clicks, but the time difference between two click which I am getting is more than the actual time difference measured manually by stopwatch.

Here is scenario: I have to save the image to device, where clicking `Start` to will start saving the image the device untill it comes with `OK` popup with finished message. So i was measuring this time interval.

Here is mine source code:

```
UiObject start_ok = mDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().text("OK"));
// Staring time measuring.......
   starting_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
   start_ok.click();
boolean complete_ok = mDevice.wait(Until.hasObject(By.text("OK")), 10000);
if (complete_ok)
{
  UiObject finished_ok = mDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().text("OK"));
  // Finished time calculating ....
  ending_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
  finished_ok.click();
}
 diff = ending_time - starting_time;
```

The above difference in time what I amgetting is more than when I am doing manually. Please suggest me a reason. Also suggest me how to overcome with this? How to measure the accurate time between two clicks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the instruction

```
boolean complete_ok = mDevice.wait(Until.hasObject(By.text("OK")), 10000);
```

your android device will wait for 10 seconds and then click OK button.

I think changing it to

```
UiObject finished_ok = mDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().text("OK"));
while(!finished_ok.exists()){
   finished_ok = mDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().text("OK"));
}
ending_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
  finished_ok.click();
```

should help.
Here you are waiting for appearance of next OK button rather than explicit wait of 10 seconds.

Comment: Also if this is white box test like espresso android testing, then we don't have to wait for button to appear. The next instruction will be executed as soon as the button appears. But espresso won't work for other application.

Comment: Still, I am getting the time difference, time is not accurate

Comment: `UiObject click_finished_ok = mDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().text("OK"));
                while(!click_finished_ok.exists())
                {
                        System.out.print(".");
                }
                // Finished time calculating ....
                ending_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                click_finished_ok.click();
            //}
            diff = ending_time - starting_time;`